# Change OK/Cancel on window.prompt?

Tags: javascript

Hi is it possible to change the OK and Cancel buttons on the window prompt to just one "Close" button? For my purpose I like that the window.prompt shows my link and is easy to copy because it's already highlighted. Here is my code:

```
function sLink()
    {   
        var ctr = map.getCenter();
        var text = "http..../viewer-emailtest.shtml?lat="+ ctr.lat().toString() + "&lng=" + ctr.lng().toString() + "&z=" + map.getZoom().toString()
        window.prompt("Copy the highlighted link below and paste into your email program to share:", text);
      }
```

Thank you!

Comment: No, it is not possible. You could just put the link in a `<input type="text" readonly="readonly" />` and use JavaScript to `focus()`.

Comment: Why are so many people using prompts for copy paste lately?

Comment: If you're not apposed to flash there are numerous solutions that let you click a button and copy to the paste buffer such as http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/

Comment: It can be done using jquery...

Comment: @atornblad I have a button on my webpage that calls the function `<input type="button" value= "Share Link" onclick="sLink()"/>`  Would I add your code to the function?

Comment: @dku.rajkumar: If changing the buttons can be done with jQuery, please give an answer!

Comment: @Andrew i ave posted the answer..

Comment: @Andrew Create an `<input>` element using `document.createElement`, set the `type` attribute to `"text"`, and the `value` attribute to the value of your `text` variable, insert the element somewhere in your DOM using `appendChild`, then call `focus()` on your input element. If that doesn't select the text in the input element, call `select()` too.

Answer (score -2):

As per OP comment, answering in jquery

```
jQuery.alerts.okButton = 'Continue';
jQuery.alerts.cancelButton = 'Cancel';
jQuery.alerts.confirm("are you sure to do ?","Confirm",function(result){
     if(result){
        alert("you selected continue");
     }else{
        alert("you selected cancel");
     }
});
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it was probably because this requires a [jQuery plugin](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/), which you don't mention.

Comment: I didn't downvote. I am OP. The other Andrew asked for the answer, not me. I'll take a look at this though thank you.

Comment: I didn't downvote either, however jQuery.alerts is now superseded by Dialogs. http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ -- which may well suffice: see the example pop-up when visiting that page. Selectable text and just a close button. (I really dislike jQuery, so I tend not to use it and I'm not well up on what's available)

Comment: ops... i got confused between two Andrews.. :(